# Vyper: Using a `decimal` type in etherscan

Tags: etherscan, vyper

I have deployed a vyper contract to etherscan that looks as such:

```py
@external
@view
def ask(x: decimal) -> decimal:
    return x
```

However, entering `0x0` into etherscan returns the following error:

```
invalid type (argument="type", value="fixed168x10", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem going back and forth between `uint` and `decimal`. Here is what I did.

1. Call Solidity interface, keeping in mind that `1 = 1/10**10`. For example when `x = 1`, inside Vyper, this will be converted to `1 / 10**10`. When `x = 10**10`, this will be `1.0` inside Vyper.
2. Inside Vyper, convert `uint` into `decimal`, and then divide by `10**10`

Solidity interface

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

interface IDecimal {
    function test(uint256 x) external pure returns (int256);
}
```

```py
@external
@pure
def test(x: uint256) -> decimal:
    x0: decimal = convert(x, decimal) / 10000000000.0
    return x0
```

Comment: right, this is great if I can change the contract code... but this is for code that is already deployed.

Comment: You can load the Solidity interface on Remix, and it should work with deployed Vyper contract

Comment: sure, but how do I use it in etherscan?